# Extension methods on enumerable-derived classes cannot infer type arguments

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

We are currently working with generics on extensions for enumerable-derived classes.
Apparently, the compiler produces an error CS0411 with extension methods if they are called on a class derived from `IEnumerable<T>` and return values that are of the enclosed `T` type.

The following example reproduces the error:

```
public class Item { }

public class CollectionType : IEnumerable<Item>
{
    public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static class CollectionExtension
{
    public static T[] DoSomething<T, TCollection>(this TCollection source)
        where TCollection : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var collection = new CollectionType();

        collection.DoSomething();

        collection.DoSomething<Item, CollectionType>(); // This works fine
    }
}
```

Calling `DoSomething()` will produce the following error:

```
The type arguments for method 'T[] [...].CollectionExtension.DoSomething<T,TCollection>(this TCollection)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

How can this happen if `TCollection` is bound to be of type `IEnumerable<T>` and `T` is also defined as a generic type parameter of `DoSomething()`?

Calling the extension method on the `CollectionType` should provide `DoSomething()` with both generic types.

Comment: How can the compiler infer `T` in every case? E.g. if I were to declare `class Foo : IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<int>`, what would the inferred type of `T` be? The fact is that the compiler doesn't even try

Comment: Also, why not declare your extension method directly on `IEnumerable<T>`, e.g. `public static T[] DoSomething(this IEnumerable<T> input)`?

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible to use the `DoSomething()` method as-is without specifying the generic types explicitly. The class `IEnumerable<T>` from which it seemingly would be possible to infer the type of `T` is located in the type constraint declaration, unfortunately C# *"...cannot infer the type parameters only from a **constraint** or return value"*. See the details here:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods]

This is issue can be solved in a different ways, you could explicitly specify the type as you have done in the example code - `collection.DoSomething<Item, CollectionType>()`, or add to `DoSomething()` an argument of type `T`, in that case C# will be able to infer the type, or get rid of the generic type TCollection, replacing it with `IEnumerable<T>` in the following way:

```
public static T[] DoSomething<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The last one I think would be a cleaner way.